# repetitive input/output entity declaration vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I've got multiple (same) input/output to declare :

```
B1_data_to_send         : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
B1_start_transmission   : out std_logic;
B1_transmission_busy    : in std_logic;

B2_data_to_send         : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
B2_start_transmission   : out std_logic;
B2_transmission_busy    : in std_logic;

B3_data_to_send         : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
B3_start_transmission   : out std_logic;
B3_transmission_busy    : in std_logic;

B4_data_to_send         : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
B4_start_transmission   : out std_logic;
B4_transmission_busy    : in std_logic;

B5_data_to_send         : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
B5_start_transmission   : out std_logic;
B5_transmission_busy    : in std_logic;

B6_data_to_send         : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
B6_start_transmission   : out std_logic;
B6_transmission_busy    : in std_logic;
```

I've got 30 block like this to create, is there a way to avoid this repetition and to create a generic block that I can instantiate with different names ?

Comment: Those are not blocks, but collections of ports. External blocks are defined by entity declarations and can be represented by component instantiations where formal ports can be associated with actual signals. Show at least one complete entity declarations and describe how these blocks are differentiated allowing determining susceptibility to the use of generic mapping. A for generate statement can instantiate a range of otherwise identical 'external blocks' when actual signals can be defined as array elements with an index provided from a generate parameter.

Comment: Ideally you would define a record type for each group of 3 ports and then an array type of these. This is possible in VHDL 2019 thanks to the _mode views_. Unfortunately, prior VHDL 2019 you cannot have different port directions in a record. And as it is very unlikely that your tools support VHDL 2019, the best you can do is to use 3 array types for your 3 ports, as @Tricky suggests.

Comment: Three ports ; each array(1 to 30) of whatever.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are what you need here. First, you will need to create an array type of std_logic_vector in a package. If you're using VHDL 2008, it can simply be an unconstrained type:

```vhdl
package types_pkg is
  type slv_array_t is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;
end package;
```

and then use this type in your entity:

```vhdl
use work.types_pkg.all;

entity your_entity is
  port (
    B_data_to_send       : in  slv_array_t     (1 to 30)(15 downto 0);
    B_start_transmission : out std_logic_vector(1 to 30);
    B_transmission_busy  : in  std_logic_vector(1 to 30)
  );
end entity;
```

Of course, any of the dimensions can come from a generic.

```vhdl
use work.types_pkg.all;

entity your_entity is
  generic (
    G_N_PORTS : natural;
    G_D_WIDTH : natural
  );
  port (
    B_data_to_send       : in  slv_array_t     (0 to G_N_PORTS-1)(G_D_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    B_start_transmission : out std_logic_vector(0 to G_N_PORTS-1);
    B_transmission_busy  : in  std_logic_vector(0 to G_N_PORTS-1) 
  );
end entity;
```